# how to fetch result from json to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, codeigniter-3

Good day, I recently learn about angularjs. Now, i'm trying to show data from json in table. I'm using codeigniter

```
<script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/app_angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('listsupport', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("<?=base_url();?>newchat/listsupport").then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.names = response.data.records;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have this Json

```
    [{"username":"0600260","password":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","Type":"TP010","Flag":1,"last_login":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.000","loginstatus":0,"alias":null,"FullName":"ZAENAL ABIDIN"},
{"username":"1602762","password":"b59c67bf196a4758191e42f76670ceba","Type":"TP001","Flag":1,"last_login":"2017-05-02 13:43:15.200","loginstatus":1,"alias":"boby","FullName":"BOBY KURNIAWAN"},
 {"username":"0903380","password":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","Type":"TP010","Flag":1,"last_login":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.000","loginstatus":0,"alias":null,"FullName":"JUDY SJARIP"},
 {"username":"1004385","password":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","Type":"TP010","Flag":1,"last_login":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.000","loginstatus":0,"alias":null,"FullName":"RENDY SETIAWAN"},
 {"username":"1004502","password":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","Type":"TP010","Flag":1,"last_login":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.000","loginstatus":0,"alias":null,"FullName":"BANGBANG IRAWAN "},{"username":"1106975","password":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","Type":"TP010","Flag":1,"last_login":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.000","loginstatus":0,"alias":null,"FullName":"ABDUL ROCHIM"},   {"username":"1501815","password":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","Type":"TP010","Flag":1,"last_login":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.000","loginstatus":0,"alias":null,"FullName":"KHAIRUNNAS "}]
```

and here is HTML table

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="listsupport"> 
             <table>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td>{{ x.FullName }}</td>

              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

With my script above, my html is empty. So how can i show the json in my HTML table with angular js ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what display `console.log(response);` ?

Comment: @Hadi Empty, and i wonder why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your addressing response properly in js...i think u need to give like `$scope.names = response.data` have a look on [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLXOkl07VGnlnP7UPnop?p=preview)

i tried with placing ur json data in to a json file

Comment: so i just need to do this  `$scope.names = response.data;`

Comment: if your getting response like how its shown in plunker then response.data is enough